# Run php mysql query for every row in table

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to create score board for my android app. I have two tables, one table named *tabulka* with columns:
 user_id, name, scoretot, scoreaverage

and another table named *statistics* with columns:
 id, cat_id, user_id, correct, wrong, score, total_question, total_score,tot_time,avg_time, quiz date, datecreated.

In *statistics* I have stored data for every game users play, so I want to sum all score for each user_id and then REPLACE it to *tabulka*. Thanks for any help

My not working code looks like this right now:

```
$queried_users=mysql_query("select user_id from tabulka")

foreach ($queried_users as $user)
$arr = get_single_value(STATISTICS,"sum(score)","user_id='".$user_id.");
foreach ($arr as $entry)
    Replace into tabulka (scoretot,user_id);
```

Comment: You have syntax errors.

Comment: rtfm: http://php.net/mysql_query. it returns a result handle, not an array. you can't foreach that handle.

Comment: A function called `get_single_value` is expected to return an array of values?

Comment: I know, but i suck at php and dont know how to solve it. I get this Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH)  on line 16

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a single query for update

```
update tabulka
join (    select user_id, sum(score) as tot 
            from statisctics group by user_id ) t on t.user_id = tabulka.user_id
set tabulka.scoretot = t.tot
```

Comment: This is the correct approach. 1 query vs 1+(number of users) queries. This will run much faster.

Comment: This gives me #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY user_id' at line 4

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 't' in 'on clause'

Comment: Thanks a million times, it works now :) its great to see that the PHP and mysql can be so simple.

Comment: @user3281831   . well  .. i'm happy .. yes .. PHP and mysql are very powerful ..and if my answer is right please mark it as accepted .